# ACF foreach Only Showing Last Value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Learning PHP as I go so need some help :) The foreach loop in the third ACF repeater below is only outputting the last value of the array. The vardump shows the entire array seems to be correct.

```
<?php if ( have_rows( 'product_table' ) ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_rows( 'product_table' ) ) : the_row(); ?>

<?php $tcols = array(); ?>
        
        <table>
    
        <h3><?php the_sub_field( 'product_table_title' ); ?></h3>
        
        <?php if ( have_rows( 'product_table_columns' ) ) : ?>
            <?php while ( have_rows( 'product_table_columns' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
                <?php $product_table_column_selected_option = get_sub_field( 'product_table_column' ); ?>
                <?php if ( $product_table_column_selected_option ) : ?>
                    <th><?php echo esc_html( $product_table_column_selected_option['label'] ); ?></th>
                    <?php $tcols[] = esc_html( $product_table_column_selected_option['value'] ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>             

        <?php if ( have_rows( 'product_table_products' ) ) : ?> 
            <?php while ( have_rows( 'product_table_products' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
                <?php $product_table_product = get_sub_field( 'product_table_product' ); ?>
                <?php if ( $product_table_product ) : ?>
                    <?php foreach($tcols as $tcol); {
                            $tdata = get_field($tcol, $product_table_product);
                                echo '<tr><td>';
                                    echo $tdata;
                                echo '</td></tr>'; } ?>
                    <?php var_dump($tcols); //This shows all the correct arrays... why does the above foreach only show the last in the array? ?>
                        
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>      
        <?php endif; ?>

            </table>
            
    <?php endwhile; ?>      
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I think there's a typo on this line `<?php foreach($tcols as $tcol); {` it has an `;` which would stop processing. I think you meant: `<?php foreach($tcols as $tcol) {`

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered in the comments already but here's the fixed code:

```php
<?php if (have_rows('product_table')) : ?>
    <?php while (have_rows('product_table')) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php $tcols = array(); ?>
    <table>
      <h3><?php the_sub_field('product_table_title'); ?></h3>
        <?php if (have_rows('product_table_columns')) : ?>
            <?php while (have_rows('product_table_columns')) : the_row(); ?>
                <?php $product_table_column_selected_option = get_sub_field('product_table_column'); ?>
                <?php if ($product_table_column_selected_option) : ?>
              <th><?php echo esc_html($product_table_column_selected_option['label']); ?></th>
                    <?php $tcols[] = esc_html($product_table_column_selected_option['value']); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if (have_rows('product_table_products')) : ?>
            <?php while (have_rows('product_table_products')) : the_row(); ?>
                <?php $product_table_product = get_sub_field('product_table_product'); ?>
                <?php if ($product_table_product) : ?>
                    <?php foreach ($tcols as $tcol) {
                        $tdata = get_field($tcol, $product_table_product);
                        echo '<tr><td>';
                        echo $tdata;
                        echo '</td></tr>';
                    }
                    ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </table>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The issue was that there was a `;` at the end of the line here: `<?php foreach($tcols as $tcol); {` That would stop the processing. Removing that would fix the issue.